# Single post page url django

Tags: python, django, url

I have a blog app in django and I want to make a template for each post but it is just not working . What can be the error?

Here's my code

### Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response , get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    posts=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Index.html', {"posts": posts})


def post(request, slug):
    print(slug)
    return render_to_response('post.html', {'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)})
```

### urls.py

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/(.*)', product_views.post),
    path('', product_views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `render_to_response`, it's obsolete. Use `render` instead.

```
def post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post})
```

Then you need to fix your URL pattern. You shouldn't use regexes like `.*` with [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path). To capture the slug, you can do:

```
path('post/<slug:slug>', product_views.post),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic DetailView to achieve what you want more easily.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', product_views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('post/<int:pk>', product_views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

views.py:

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
```

[Here is a nice tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views) from Mozilla that walks you through.